# DISTINCT with joins

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables:

```
m (id, userid, date)
s (userid, locationid)
l (locationid, location)
```

I'd like to do a join like this:

```
SELECT m.*, s.*, l.*
FROM m
LEFT JOIN s ON m.userid = s.userid
LEFT JOIN l ON s.locationid = l.locationid
GROUP BY l.locationid
ORDER BY m.date DESC
LIMIT 200
```

However I'm noticing that the `GROUP BY` is changing the selection set of my results. I'm expecting to see the last (newest) n records in my `m` table skipping over those with repeated location ids. It seems, rather, that it's starting with much earlier (older) records from m table.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using? MySQL can produce incorrect results with `GROUP BY`

Comment: Your `group by` usage is invalid, but MySQL chooses to return random data rather then rejecting it (as every other DBMS does) See e.g. here: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: I appreciate the 'you're doing this wrong' comments. You're confirming what I already know.

Using MySql 5.1.73-1

Comment: 5.1 is mighty old; plan on updating to 5.5 or 5.6 or 5.7.

Comment: Upgrading MySQL will produce the expected results?

Answer (score 1):

It is improper to `GROUP BY` one column, but then list more than that one column in the `SELECT` list (unless the other columns are 1:1 with respect to the group-by column).  In this case, the engine is free to pick whatever values it likes for the extra columns.

Perhaps you need [*Groupwise Max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) code.

Comment: and more, by default on many new installations (> 5.6 and newer)  this is disabled by default sql_mode.

Comment: @a_vlad only on 5.7 I think.

Comment: may be You are right, but right now finish project for migrate 5.1 -> 5.6 and this is was one of tasks - convert legacy queries for proper form. but not sure for 100%, may be it specific of this installation

Comment: @a_vlad - `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is in 5.5 and 5.6, but defaults to ON in 5.7.5.  In the latter version, more code was added to avoid a number of false alarms.